# Command outputs logs when run locally but not when run on server

Tags: .net, automated-tests, dotnet-test

When I run `dotnet test --filter "Category=rda"` on my local PC the dos terminal outputs all logging. If I then run the same on one of my servers no logs are output. How do I fix this

Comment: Please don't use tag `[dos]` for Windows command prompt questions; I edited your question to remove it. Although many people call the Windows command prompt "DOS", that is technically wrong since it isn't DOS anymore (not since Windows XP)

Answer (score 0):

I added `--logger:"console;verbosity=detailed"`